# How are percents and main author for community-wiki posts computed?

Tags: support, edits, community-wiki

In [a community-wiki answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/169936/158700) which I [edited](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/169936/revisions) recently, I added one hyperlink, added one comma and removed another. From that time, I’ve been reported as the main contributor to the answer, although the changes I made were pretty small.

```
community wiki
2 revs, 2 users 56%
Melebius
```

I find this devaluing the [original author’s contribution](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/169936/1)…

The page [Edit community wiki in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) says:

> community wiki posts show the editor with the highest percentage of the remaining post in the current version in the author field.

And the [accepted answer to What does the % in the Community Wiki box mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190209/217657) says:

> It's not the last editor, it's the most prolific editor, based on a very naive calculation involving lines of the post that were changed.

So I am called “the most prolific editor” because I edited *something* (although a little bit) in all paragraphs? Are the *changed lines* interpreted as lines of code, ending with the newline character (paragraphs in fact), and not the lines displayed in browser?

One more thing, the page says `2 users 56%`. Where are the remaining 44%? Only two users have been involved in the [post’s history](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/169936/revisions), so I’d expect their contribution to be 100%.

Comment: Slightly related (though that particular problem has been fixed): *[Indentation changes in markdown diff should be less noisy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81360/indentation-changes-in-markdown-diff-should-be-less-noisy)*

Comment: I far as I remember, there was ***a regression*** (several years later) for the fix in the duplicate. Perhaps due to changes to the diff functions? I don't know if it was fixed or not.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer in the linked question is correct, I'll re-post the relevant part:

> based on a **very naive** calculation

This means the calculation is super simple: if the post has 9 lines, and you changed 5 lines, that's 56% change.

The 56% is the amount of changes the visible editor has made, not the sum of all changes.

Here's [an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/331007#331007) where a user added four periods to a Community Wiki answer and now supposedly owns 67% of the post.

Comment: I am sorry, still not clear. Why are those edited `56%` shown together with `2 users` which have contributed 100% in fact? And where do you find the post is 9 lines long? I have only found 5 newlines (line breaks), it could be 6 when counting the end of the post.

Comment: @Melebius The "2 users" mean two users, overall, took part in writing the post, and the percentage shown is the percentage of change done by the "top" editor. As for 9 lines it was just a guess since 5/9 is 56% that fits what you see. Maybe it considers any markdown element as "line", I'm not sure about this part.

Comment: @JL2210 umm.. no. Sorry, thought you want to link to it or something like that. You can suggest that edit to [my answer under the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331007/152859), which is already CW. I don't mind the rep loss, but ordinary posts should not be used for testing.